# how do you sent a tweet from arduino via arduino wifi shield?

Tags: arduino

i used the examples that is in built in arduino to receive tweets. but i wish to receive and write a tweet to a specific account. how do i possibly do that?

i followed the codes from the arduino example.
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiTwitterClient

but in the codes, it didnt specify where the tweets were coming from. when i run the codes, i received tweets which comes from other tweets which is unknown to me.

Comment: @LeonHeller - Are questions about embedded programming outside the scope? I can see that it is borderline, but still within the FAQ (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: This is a pure software problem.

Comment: Pure software problem on the arduino, I wont close it and I dont think it makes sense to close it. This user is attempting to add features to an embedded platform he is working on. To me it seems many realities here may relate to both [so] and EE.SE. I am supporting leaving this open. Lets discuss this point [here though](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-much-software-is-on-topic?cb=1)

Comment: Check this link out .... http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2014/01/getting-data-from-web-server-using-arduino-wifi.html ..... They have shared a complete method of how you can get data from a web server via Arduino Wifi.

Comment: This question and its answers are obsolete due to changes in technology and no longer useful.

Answer (score 2):

The code you link to only looks at a user's tweets.

Change 'arduino' in the following line to the twitter account you wish to read

```
client.println("GET /1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=arduino HTTP/1.1");
```

To send posts you need to send a HTTP POST packet, e.g. see

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

For the other api commands: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

But this all requires authentication:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

The people at stackoverflow will know how to do it!

Comment: It sounds like you know a decent bit of it, I wish you could add the last bit of information, I have seen arduinos tweeting before, and although it is not my cup of tea, it exists.

Comment: @Kortuk - I just got that information from a bit of googling and previous experience with HTTP messaging. I haven't done the tweeting myself so I can't add that info.

Comment: was hoping that would only take a bit of googling also.

Answer (score 0):

That twitter library doesn't actually work anymore.
It is a shame Arduino is unable to connect to the Twitter API directly but until Arduino can run Linux and or do oAuth we are stuck.

I have a solution that again works with a middle-man but you don't need a library and you can be your own middle-man if you can host a PHP script. 
http://www.brianmoreau.com/projects/social-devices/arduino-tweet-switch.php